# "validation (CSS 3.0) "align-item" is not a known css property name" error on asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor

"align-item" doesn't show up when I search for it, "display: flex;" also doesn't but instead "display: flexbox;" shows up, and "justify-content" doesn't show up as well.
I have been trying to search for a solution but I got nothing. Please someone help.

I have tried giving it Height but still no luck, the same error appears!

Comment: Try `align-items` (with s at the end) https://caniuse.com/?search=align-items

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.